# c++ using of iconv on Windows with Mingw compiler

Tags: c++, windows, mingw, iconv

Good time of day!

I compiled this code with g++ 4.7.2  on Ubuntu successfully, but I have problems with compiling it on Windows with Mingw.

Simplified Code:

```
 size_t string_length=some_size;
 char arr_symb[string_length+1];

 char *outputde=arr_symb;
 iconv_t type=iconv_open("UTF-8","WINDOWS-1251");

char output[some_size];

char *p1=arr_symb;
char *p2=output;

if (   iconv(type, &p1,&string_length, &p2, &output_length ) == -1 )// here 
        // is mistake, it doesn't like pointers p1 and p2 but I wonder why

  log_info("something went wrong");
```

On Linux  with G++ it can be compiled  and works fine as  it should. With Mingw I get errors:

[image]

I wonder, if it works fine with g++ , why does mingw treat it like it's mistaken?

Thanks in advance!

**ADDITION**
My Mingw version is 4.4.0 
GCC version is  4.7.2

Comment: And what version of GCC does your MinGW use?

Comment: Mingw version is 4.4.0  and
GCC version is 4.7.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks all for your attention, problem is solved, but it's all strange to me (it's still unclear )

Although  the function has such prototype,

[image]

With MinGW it should  be called so:

[image]

So, the problem is that input string for MinGW should be passed as constant (also it doesn't have such prototype).

Answer (score 1):

See these declarations:

```
  int  a[10];
  int* b = malloc(10 * sizeof(int));
```

Looks and feels the same, but:

A pointer to an array of ints (*b) is NOT the same as an array of ints (a)! So a pointer to an array (*) is also not the same as a pointer to a pointer (**)!

The dereferencing for the pointer needs one more level!

Comment: I appreciate your registering for the sake of answering my question